# Something is checking my Gmail on set intervals

Tags: gmail

As you can see from the picture something is leaving a timestamp in my Gmail if I leave it open in the browser while AFK.

It is almost always happening every hour and I don't understand why. Does anyone have the same problem?

I don't use any mailing app nor IMAP or POP3.

It also doesn't seem to be happening every hour, sometimes it would miss a couple of hours and then resume.
[image]

Comment: A natural thing to do would be to compare the IP address shown to the addresses of your computers.

Comment: The IP is the same as is the session

Comment: So, I'd say what you see is the "heartbeat" activity: it records the fact that the browser keeps an open Gmail session. A useful feature because it makes the existence of this session apparent (otherwise, it'd scroll out of view after a while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. This is simply the Gmail code in your open browser session checking your mailbox every once in a while to see if it needs to update the message list. Gmail uses [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) extensively; it doesn't require a page load to do most of what it does.